# WPF - How to display TreeView with a mix of self-referencing and external entities

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, treeview, self-reference

I am trying to render a TreeView with a mix of self-referencing and external entities but cannot find any solution that works..

I have the following models:

```
# Folder
-> string Name
-> Folder ParentFolder
-> Collection<Folder> Children
-> Collection<Document> Documents

# Document
-> string Name
-> Folder Folder
```

I'm trying to display it as a file system hierarchy like this:

```
+ Folder 1
  + Folder 1.1
    - Doc 1
    - Doc 2
+ Folder 2
  + Folder 2.1
  + Folder 2.2
    - Doc 3
  - Doc 4
```

The ViewModel bound to the view contains a `Collection<Folder> Folders`.

I've tried a lot of different combination in the XAML with simple binding and MultiBinding but without success..
Here is my **current** XAML (which doesn't work because not displaying the hierarchy):

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Folders}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Folder}">
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
                <MultiBinding>
                    <Binding Path="Children" />
                    <Binding Path="Documents" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>

            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Background="Blue"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Document}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Background="Red"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

I've also tried the following that displays the folders hierarchy but not the documents (which is I think due to not specifying the `Documents` property anywhere in the XAML but not sure how..):

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Folders}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" DataType="{x:Type model:Folder}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Document}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Background="Red"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current XAML should work if you just define and use a converter that creates a composite collection of folders and documents:

```
public class Converter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        IEnumerable<object> folders = values[0] as IEnumerable<object>;
        IEnumerable<object> docs = values[1] as IEnumerable<object>;

        if (folders != null && docs != null)
            return Enumerable.Concat(folders, docs);
        else if (folders != null)
            return folders;
        else if (docs != null)
            return docs;

        return null;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) =>
        throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Folders}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Folder}">
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
                <MultiBinding>
                    <MultiBinding.Converter>
                        <model:Converter />
                    </MultiBinding.Converter>
                    <Binding Path="Children" />
                    <Binding Path="Documents" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemsSource>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Background="Blue"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:Document}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Background="Red"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```